# Laravel Schedule 5.4 names like `everyMinute()` not working

Tags: php, laravel, scheduler, jobs

I am using Laravel 5.4

When I use `everyMinute()` it always return an error

```
In FieldFactory.php line 46:

  5 is not a valid position
```

when I convert it to `cron('* * * * *')` then it is working.

---

Error:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new TestJob())->everyMinute();
}
```

Working:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->job(new TestJob())->cron('* * * * *');
}
```

Comment: Could you include some snippets of the code you are trying to run?

Comment: I have added the snippet.

Comment: Could you add the full stack trace using the verbose flag on the schedule command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it via `composer update`. I think there's a package that rely on Laravel 5.5 or higher. Because 5.5 only require `->cron('* * * * *')`  and Laravel 5.4 accepts `->cron('* * * * * *')`